# How to set up two default routes in linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking

### TL;DR

How to set up two default routes in linux (corresponding to two interfaces), such that incoming traffic from both interfaces is accepted.

### Scenario

I have a host having two NICs `eth0` and `eth1`. Its connected to two networks, say:

- Dev: `eth0`, IP: `1.1.1.4`, Netmask: `255.255.255.0`, Gateway: `1.1.1.1`
- Dev: `eth1`, IP: `2.2.2.4`, Netmask: `255.255.255.0`, Gateway: `2.2.2.1`

(Both networks are connected to the internet.)

The routes are (`ip route show`):

```
default via 1.1.1.1 dev eth0 metric 1
default via 2.2.2.1 dev eth1 metric 2
1.1.1.0/24 dev eth0 src 1.1.1.4
2.2.2.0/24 dev eth1 src 2.2.2.4
```

(Lower metric means higher priority.)

---

Now when someone pings `2.2.2.4` from some external host (say `4.4.4.4`), there is no reply.

The output of `tcpdump -i eth1` on my host is:

```
22:41:27.431539 IP 4.4.4.4 > 2.2.2.4: ICMP echo request, id 8625, seq 4, length 64
22:41:28.439492 IP 4.4.4.4 > 2.2.2.4: ICMP echo request, id 8625, seq 5, length 64
22:41:29.447666 IP 4.4.4.4 > 2.2.2.4: ICMP echo request, id 8625, seq 6, length 64
22:41:30.455528 IP 4.4.4.4 > 2.2.2.4: ICMP echo request, id 8625, seq 7, length 64
```

After some research, it turns out that when linux network stack receives a packet from `4.4.4.4`, it checks its routing table to see what interface should have been used for `4.4.4.4` (which is `eth0` in the routing table). Now, since the packet came from `eth1` interface, linux simply discards it (This policy is probably to prevent IP spoofing).

---

What I want is is:

- Outgoing traffic (locally originated) should use `eth0` interface by default.
- Incoming traffic should be accepted from both interfaces. (So `4.4.4.4` should be able to ping both `1.1.1.4` and `2.2.2.4`)

Comment: Use `iptables` for marking packets based on source address, and let route using this mark. There are a plenty of howtos on internet. http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.netfilter.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using iproute2 you can do something like this:

```
echo "1 admin" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo "2 users" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip rule add from 192.168.122.40/32 dev eth0 table admin
ip rule add from 192.168.123.41/32 dev eth1 table users

ip route add default via 192.168.122.1 dev eth0 table admin
ip route add default via 192.168.123.1 dev eth1 table users
```

Now you will have two routing table with two gateways.

Answer (score 4):

This phenomena is called unicast rpf (reverse path forwarding) as a standard but reverse path filter in Linux. You may disable this without any important negative consequences (unless you're an isp.. and a router).

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter
```

Then your example should work as you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

In case your application binds to `0.0.0.0` it is also required to add rules like:

`ip rule add from 0.0.0.0/32 to 192.168.122.0/24 dev eth0 table admin`

`ip rule add from 0.0.0.0/32 to 192.168.123.0/24 dev eth1 table users`

Comment: 0.0.0.0/32 is the very first host address of the Internet, and, as part of the 0.0.0.0/8 network it is reserved, I think you mean 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: 0.0.0.0/0 would mean the whole ipv4 range in cidr notation. The so called "unspecified" address is in ipv4 0.0.0.0/32, or in ipv6 :: /128. These addresses are used to indicate that there is no address available. The 0.0.0.0/8 block is reserved and only valid for source addresses.