# Ping is working but curl not working on a specific interface

Tags: iptables, ip, route

I would like to be able to make a curl through 2 different interfaces: ppp0 (data connection) and enp3s0 (ethernet connection).

ppp0 connection is mounted by pppd. This gives the following route table:

```
$ route -n
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0
192.168.10.110  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

`192.168.10.110` is my data provider's DNS address.

Ping is working fine through both interfaces:

```
$ ping -I enp3s0 -c 3 8.8.8.8 && ping -I ppp0 -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.1.74 enp3s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=4.11 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=3.88 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=3.82 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.825/3.941/4.116/0.145 ms
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.153.180.174 ppp0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=952 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=618 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=451 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 451.976/674.295/952.759/208.263 ms
```

But curl is not working:

```
$ curl --interface enp3s0 http://45.32.148.9/json && curl --interface ppp0 http://45.32.148.9/json
{"as":"AS3215 Orange","city":"Paris","country":"France","countryCode":"FR","isp":"Orange","lat":48.8628,"lon":2.3292,"org":"Orange","query":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","region":"IDF","regionName":"Île-de-France","status":"success","timezone":"Europe/Paris","zip":"75001"}
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 45.32.148.9 port 80: Connection timed out
```

My question is: how can-I make curl working through both interface?

PS: Below my sysctl configuration

```
$ sysctl -a | grep ipv4
net.ipv4.cipso_cache_bucket_size = 10
net.ipv4.cipso_cache_enable = 1
net.ipv4.cipso_rbm_optfmt = 0
net.ipv4.cipso_rbm_strictvalid = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.all.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.all.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.default.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.default.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.promote_secondaries = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.promote_secondaries = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.promote_secondaries = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.promote_secondaries = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.accept_source_route = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.disable_policy = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.disable_xfrm = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.lo.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.lo.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.accept_source_route = 1
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.promote_secondaries = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s18u1u4i4.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.promote_secondaries = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s19u1u3i4.tag = 0
net.ipv4.fib_multipath_use_neigh = 0
net.ipv4.fwmark_reflect = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_errors_use_inbound_ifaddr = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_msgs_burst = 50
net.ipv4.icmp_msgs_per_sec = 1000
net.ipv4.icmp_ratelimit = 1000
net.ipv4.icmp_ratemask = 6168
net.ipv4.igmp_link_local_mcast_reports = 1
net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships = 20
net.ipv4.igmp_max_msf = 10
net.ipv4.igmp_qrv = 2
net.ipv4.inet_peer_maxttl = 600
net.ipv4.inet_peer_minttl = 120
net.ipv4.inet_peer_threshold = 65664
net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 64
net.ipv4.ip_dynaddr = 0
net.ipv4.ip_early_demux = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward_use_pmtu = 0
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999
net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports = 
net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 0
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 0
net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 4194304
net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh = 3145728
net.ipv4.ipfrag_max_dist = 64
net.ipv4.ipfrag_secret_interval = 0
net.ipv4.ipfrag_time = 30
net.ipv4.neigh.default.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.default.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.default.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.default.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 128
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 512
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 1024
net.ipv4.neigh.default.locktime = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.default.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.default.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.default.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv4.neigh.default.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.default.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.default.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.default.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv4.neigh.default.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.locktime = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.locktime = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv4.neigh.enp2s0.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.locktime = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv4.neigh.enp3s0.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.locktime = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.locktime = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv4.neigh.ppp0.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.locktime = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s18u1u4i4.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.locktime = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv4.neigh.wwp0s19u1u3i4.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 1   0
net.ipv4.route.error_burst = 5000
net.ipv4.route.error_cost = 1000
net.ipv4.route.gc_elasticity = 8
net.ipv4.route.gc_interval = 60
net.ipv4.route.gc_min_interval = 0
net.ipv4.route.gc_min_interval_ms = 500
net.ipv4.route.gc_thresh = -1
net.ipv4.route.gc_timeout = 300
net.ipv4.route.max_size = 2147483647
net.ipv4.route.min_adv_mss = 256
net.ipv4.route.min_pmtu = 552
net.ipv4.route.mtu_expires = 600
net.ipv4.route.redirect_load = 20
net.ipv4.route.redirect_number = 9
net.ipv4.route.redirect_silence = 20480
net.ipv4.tcp_abort_on_overflow = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_adv_win_scale = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_allowed_congestion_control = cubic reno
net.ipv4.tcp_app_win = 31
net.ipv4.tcp_autocorking = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control = cubic reno
net.ipv4.tcp_base_mss = 1024
net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit = 1000
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic
net.ipv4.tcp_dsack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_early_retrans = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_ecn = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_ecn_fallback = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_frto = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_fwmark_accept = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_invalid_ratelimit = 500
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
net.ipv4.tcp_limit_output_bytes = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_low_latency = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 8192
net.ipv4.tcp_max_reordering = 300
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 128
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 8192
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 21423    28565   42846
net.ipv4.tcp_min_rtt_wlen = 300
net.ipv4.tcp_min_tso_segs = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_notsent_lowat = -1
net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_pacing_ca_ratio = 120
net.ipv4.tcp_pacing_ss_ratio = 200
net.ipv4.tcp_probe_interval = 600
net.ipv4.tcp_probe_threshold = 8
net.ipv4.tcp_recovery = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_reordering = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_retrans_collapse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_retries1 = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_retries2 = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096    87380   6291456
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_stdurg = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 6
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_thin_dupack = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_thin_linear_timeouts = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tso_win_divisor = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096    16384   4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_workaround_signed_windows = 0
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 42846    57131   85692
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 4096
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 4096
net.ipv4.xfrm4_gc_thresh = 2147483647
```

Answer (score 1):

Ping 8.8.8.8 works fine, OK, but note that it has **nothing to do** with the issue:

```
Failed to connect to 45.32.148.9 port 80
```

Hint: ask yourself

> Can 45.32.148.9 be reached through 192.168.1.1 as the routing table
>   shows?

Then

> Does firewall allow traffic from *enp3s0* to 45.32.148.9 port 80?

Comment: Well I guess this is a route issue as when I delete the `default` route on `enp3s0` and create one on `ppp0`, `ppp0` curl is working and `enp3s0` curl failed.

Comment: Also if I stop the firewal `systemctl stop firewalld` I still have the issue. So this is definitely a route issue

Comment: It looks like a route issue, indeed. Maybe this post helps you --> (http://serverfault.com/questions/823058/how-to-set-up-two-default-routes-in-linux)