# Socket send redirected to a different interface than what it is bound to

Tags: linux, socket

There are 2 NICs (network interface cards) with IPs `IP0` and `IP1` as primary addresses given to them as seen in the kernel routing table via `ip route`. Say a TCP socket is bound to `IP0` (and some port `P0`). So it will receive packets destined to `IP0:P0` and this part I understand. When it wants to send out data to Destination `IP-Dest:Port-Dest`, the kernel routing table says this should ultimately go via the other NIC with primary IP as `IP1`. I want to know what is the rule in such cases. Does the kernel drop the packet as the sender (the socket) was bound to a different NIC with different IP (`IP0`) or does it send it via the other NIC but ignore the IP associated with it (`IP1`) and instead stamp the source IP as `IP0` to which the socket was bound or (the other way around) ignore `IP0` and stamp the source as `IP1` while still sending over the other NIC or are there other rules that govern the behaviour here and results could vary ?

A follow up question: when binding to all interfaces via `0.0.0.0` and port `0`, is the same (whatever kernel chooses) port number chosen for all interfaces for this socket or there is no such guarantee and it could choose `IP0:P0` and `IP1:P1` where `P0 != P1` or does it depend on protocol or some other factor ?

Answer (score 0):

If the application binds to `0.0.0.0` the ports will be the same for all interfaces.

Still the routing is getting tricky when binding to `0.0.0.0`. Often software generates the packets then with `0.0.0.0` source in IP `SRC`. This leads to ending up on the default routing table, which is typically the first interfaces gateway/subnet.

Therefore it is needed to setup two independent routing tables:

https://serverfault.com/a/823061/476056

And specify routing based on destination for the interfaces

https://serverfault.com/a/918875/476056

Comment: Pls note that in my primary question, the socket is not bound to 0.0.0.0. It's bound only to `IP0` and sends out something to `IP-Dest` which from the routing table should go out of the other NIC with other IP `IP1`. What happens in this case (pls see the question for more details) ?